# Procedimiento de almacenado con case

Tags: sql, stored-procedure

Tengo este Stored Procedure donde necesito hacer una búsqueda por apellido materno o paterno

Teniendo en cuenta que en mi grilla se muestran ambos concatenados como apellidos, tal como esta en el select

Pero al hacerlo con el case se me complica ya que no puedo tener los dos campos en una sola condicion :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[IN_obtenerEmplSucEmp1]
    @Rut varchar(18),   
    @Apellidos varchar(100), 
    @codsuc INT,
    @codemp INT

AS

SELECT 
        per_rut_per, 
        per_nom_per, 
        (per_ape_pat+' '+per_ape_mat) AS Apellidos, 
        per_anx_per, 
        per_cor_ele,
        par1.par_des_par as per_emp_per, 
        par2.par_des_par as per_suc_per 
    FROM PER 
    INNER JOIN PAR as par1 ON PAR1.PAR_COD_TAB = 18  AND par1.PAR_COD_PAR = PER_emp_PER
    INNER JOIN PAR AS PAR2 ON PAR2.PAR_COD_TAB = 13  AND PAR2.PAR_COD_PAR = per_suc_per

    where   per_rut_per = CASE @Rut WHEN '' THEN per_rut_per ELSE @Rut END AND
            per_ape_pat like CASE @Apellidos WHEN '' THEN per_ape_pat ELSE @Apellidos+'%' END and   
            per_suc_per = CASE @codsuc WHEN 0 THEN per_suc_per ELSE @CODsuc END and
            per_emp_per = CASE @codemp WHEN 0 THEN per_emp_per ELSE @CODemp END
```

¿Cómo lo puedo resolver?

Comment: Que DBMS usas? SQL Server, MySql...

Comment: sql server pero ya lo resolvi, ahora tengo drama en hacer la busqueda en los textbox por rut o por apellido, en el sp funciona bien , pero no en el programa solo me busca por apellido

Comment: @RicconterSalazar abre otra pregunta para la búsqueda en los textbox, ¿en que esta hecha la aplicación?

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a que deseas buscar `en el WHERE` por apellido materno o paterno, *en lugar de la cláusula CASE*, puedes modificar tu consulta de esta manera:

```
WHERE (per_ape_pat LIKE '%'+@Apellidos+'%' OR per_ape_mat LIKE '%'+@Apellidos+'%')
```